# JQuery can not get element parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a problem using JQuery to get parent element.

HTML

```
<div class="panel-body">
<!--this is the parent element I want to achieve --> 
<div class="form-group" data-required="true">
<label for="emYwndazrRuAeKpZf" class="control-label">Model:</label>
<select class="auto-select form-control" name="items.0.model" id="emYwndazrRuAeKpZf" required="" data-schema-key="items.0.model" autocomplete="off">
<!--this is the child I am trying to get parent -->
<option value="">(Select One)</option>
<option value="AM3" data-description="iHealth Wireless Activity and Sleep Tracker" data-singleprice="20">AM3</option>
<option value="BP5" data-description="bp5" data-singleprice="15">BP5</option> 
<option value="BP3" data-description="BP3" data-singleprice="21">BP3</option>
</select>    
<span class="help-block"></span>
</div>
```

JS

```
var $sel = $('.auto-select');
var data = $sel.find(':selected').data();
var $parent = $sel.parent('.panel-body');
console.log($parent.html());
console.log($sel.parent(".panel-body").html())
_.each( data, function(val,key){
    console.log("input[name$='"+key+"']"); 
    $parent.find("input[name$='"+key+"']").val(val)
```

for the two console.log I got undefined error.
I am not sure where I am doing wrong, can someone help me with these?
thanks a lot

Comment: Please fix your HTML comments first.

Comment: yes, please post clear code which can be worked on. We don't know what your item is and what your model is. Its better to ask something on sample html code or even if you want to ask it on this code at least please post readable code

Comment: @nikhil, fixing code is often not okay. It may well be that the issue was directly caused by the HTML comments that you fixed. Also, you should have edited the question to fix _all_ formatting problems, e. g. splitting the HTML and the JS code blocks.

Comment: @Xufox - I agree with you. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: @JunChen Zhu - There is an closing bracket missing for _.each - is it missing only in the question or in the actual code as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you that pointing out I posted this question in a bad formatting. I will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

From [jquery.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)
`.parent` only traverse one dom level, while `.parents` traverse many, here you have to use `.parents` as your `select` is not a direct children of `.panel-body`, hierachy is `.panel-body .form-group select`.

Created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sad7p9Ls/2/)

code is here:

```
var $sel = $('.auto-select');
var data = $sel.find(':selected').data();
var $parent = $sel.parents('.panel-body');
console.log($parent.html());
console.log($sel.parent(".panel-body").html())
```

Also, your `div.panel-body` is not enclosed by `</div>` and I don't know do you at least put you js code in `<script>`, better not make typo when asking.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. The problem is fixed. I did missed a </div> and that was a typo. I changed parent to parents and problem is fixed.  thank you so much for the help.